# django fragment caching for anonymous users only

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cache

I want to use django fragment caching for anonymous users, but give authenticated users fresh data. This seems to work fine:

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}

    {% load cache %}
    {% cache 300 "my-cache-fragment" %}
        <b>I have to write this out twice</b>
    {% endcache %}

{% else %}

    <b>I have to write this out twice</b>

{% endif %}
```

The only problem is that I have to repeat the html to be cached. Is there some clever way around this, other than putting it in an include? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the cache timeout to zero for authenticated users.

views.py:

```
context = {
    "cache_timeout": 300 if request.user.is_anonymous() else 0,
}
```

Template:

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache cache_timeout "my-cache-fragment" %}
    <b>I have to write this only once</b>
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: This is [a similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24519003/64911) that puts all the logic in the template instead (for better or worse).

Answer (score 1):

```
{% with cache_timeout=user.is_staff|yesno:"0,300" %}
    {% cache cache_timeout cacheidentifier user.is_staff %}
            your content here
    {% endcache %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem...

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 300 "my-cache-fragment" %}
    <b>I have to write this out twice</b>
{% endcache %}

{% if not user.is_anonymous %}
    <b>And this is the extra uncached stuff for authenticated users</b>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It's the same stuff for both anonymous and authenticated users. The only difference is that one is inside the cache tags and one is outside.

Comment: Although this is a valid approach, it might break in a different situation:
e.g. having a `{% block something %}{% endblock %}` will raise an error (same blocktag used more than once is not allowed)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify caching with passing extra parameters to `cache` tag like:

```
{% cache 500 sidebar request.user.is_anonymous %}
```

Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) for more info...
But this will also cache data for *logged-in* users too...

Probably you have to write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). You can start by inspecting existing `cache` tag and create a custom tag based on that code. But do not forget, django caching is quite strong and complex(like supporting different languages in template caching).